# how to detect if a word from a db is contained into a sent string

Tags: mysql, string-comparison

I have this scenario:

I have a mysql database, with a table that contain strings.
I send a string through a post/get/whatever request to a script that must check if a string from the table is contained into the sent string.

For example I have the word "test" in the table and I send the word "atesta". I want to return true.

The other way around (check if the word is contained inside the database) is simple (select bla bla where column like "%string%").

I hope my way of describing the problem is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the arguments. Then use the the concatenation operator `||` to add the `%`, front and back:

```
WHERE 'string' LIKE ('%' || column || '%')
```

or the concatenation function:

```
WHERE 'string' LIKE CONCAT('%', column, '%')
```

---

I should mention that default settings have the `||` operator act as a synonym for logical `OR` operator. To act as the standard concatenation operator, the server has to run in [`ANSI` mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) (read about the `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` detail).

Comment: Tried... but doesn't work. My query: SELECT * FROM words WHERE 'bab' LIKE ('%' || column || '%'). Instead it worked with CONCAT function in query.